# Creating a radiused corner in Altium Designer?

Tags: altium, layout

What is the best way to create a radiused corner in Altium Designer when the angle is not a multiple of 90 degrees?

For instance I need to add a 0.1mm radius to the corners circled in blue below:

[image]

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Comment: Asked on Altium's forum.  Thanks.